# mfmailcomposer crash on IOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm using xcode 5.0 when i run the application on IOS 6 simulator or on a device with the same IOS runs perfectly, if i run with IOS 7 simulator or device crash with the following error:

```
    2013-10-02 11:01:48.992 KLUSCIENCE3U04[1146:a0b] -[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17071970
2013-10-02 11:01:48.994 KLUSCIENCE3U04[1146:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17071970'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x03e9f5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0277c8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x03f3c903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x03e8f90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x03e8f4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x03e1f9cc CFStringGetLength + 140
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x03e23491 CFStringAppend + 177
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x03e1de73 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 8611
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x03e5e9b4 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux + 116
    9   Foundation                          0x01f148d0 -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] + 143
    10  Foundation                          0x01f1594d +[NSString stringWithFormat:] + 88
    11  UIKit                               0x0099a8c4 -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 2649
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x03e93d1d __invoking___ + 29
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x03e93c2a -[NSInvocation invoke] + 362
    14  UIKit                               0x0098a25f -[_UIDelayedPresentationContext finishDelayedPresentation:] + 238
    15  UIKit                               0x00999ae6 -[UIViewController _endDelayingPresentation] + 104
    16  MessageUI                           0x00762e12 -[MFMailComposeInternalViewController _endDelayingCompositionPresentation] + 193
    17  MessageUI                           0x007637fd -[MFMailComposeInternalViewController _finishServiceViewControllerRequestWithSuccess:] + 300
    18  MessageUI                           0x00763601 __68-[MFMailComposeInternalViewController _configureRemoteViewContoller]_block_invoke + 205
    19  MessageUI                           0x0076367b __68-[MFMailComposeInternalViewController _configureRemoteViewContoller]_block_invoke184 + 26
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x03e93d1d __invoking___ + 29
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x03e93c2a -[NSInvocation invoke] + 362
    22  UIKit                               0x00e709ef __63-[_UIViewServiceInterface connection:handleInvocation:isReply:]_block_invoke + 36
    23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02a7f818 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02a944b0 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02a82766 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 340
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x03f04a5e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x03e4572b __CFRunLoopRun + 1963
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x03e44b33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x03e4494b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x038279d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x038277fe GSEventRun + 104
    32  UIKit                               0x0087c94b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    33  KLUSCIENCE3U04                      0x000b86b6 main + 134
    34  KLUSCIENCE3U04                      0x00002b15 start + 53
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here is the code:

```
-(void)sendEmail
{
    @try {
        NSString *imageToAttach1,*imageToAttach2, *imageName;
        NSInteger i = carousel.currentItemIndex;
        imageToAttach1 = [images objectAtIndex:i];
        imageToAttach2 = [description objectAtIndex:i];

        // Attach image1 to the email
        imageName = [imageToAttach1 substringToIndex:[imageToAttach1 length]-4];
        NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"png"];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

        // Attach image2 to the email
        imageName = [imageToAttach2 substringToIndex:[imageToAttach2 length]-4];
        NSString *imagePath2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"png"];
        NSData *imageData2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath2];

        if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
        {
            MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

            [picker setSubject:@"KLU Glossary"];
            [picker addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:imageToAttach1];
            [picker addAttachmentData:imageData2 mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:imageToAttach2];

            [picker setMessageBody:@"Glossary by KLU" isHTML:NO];
            picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
            [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
            [picker release];
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSString *error = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@: %@",[exception name], [exception reason]];
        NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
    }
}

-(void) mailComposeController: (MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult: (MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            break;
        default:
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email" message:@"Sending Failed – Unknown Error  "
                                                        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];
            }
        break;
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: What type is the `imageToAttach1` variable? Which line of code is causing the crash? Why is `isHTML:` set to `YES` when the body is not HTML?

Comment: i updated the question with the code and still have the same problem

Comment: What kind of objects are in the `images` and the `description` array? And for the 2nd time - which line of code is actually causing the crash? Stop making us guess. Put some effort into helping us help you. Also, why don't you use the debugger and step through this code. Check the values of your variables. You are getting an `NSArray` where you are expecting an `NSString`.

Comment: The crash is not in any of the lines above, even if i run with debugger it finish (apparently) the subroutine, but if i do not run the sendEmail routine do not crash the app. The funniest thing is this is running on IOS 6, but not in IOS 7. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: The crash happens even if i do not include subject and/or attachments

Comment: I'd recommend to debug with "All Exceptions" breakpoint enabled.